# Are these mispronunciations by my British English text-to-speech engine a reflection of an actual British English usage?

Tags: british-english, abbreviations, pronunciation-vs-spelling

A little context: I'm a native speaker of American English. I use Google's text-to-speech engine with the British voice, as I find the roboticness (roboticity?) of delivery to be less distracting in a less familiar accent. However, I'm occasionally left scratching my head over particular pronunciations.

Some of these are clearly based on English language formation rules--for example, for some time the proper name "Ian" was said as just a sort of swallowed /n/ sound, likely because of a system rule about words ending in -ian (such as logician or Hessian; presumably there was some other rule governing guardian and the like).

However, two of these have me stumped. **"M'"** (as in m'lady or m'lord, *but NOT m'self*) is pronounced something like "MASHna" (/**ˈmæʃ-nə**/), and **"hon"** (the short form of "honey", as in "can I get you a warm-up on your coffee, hon?") sounds to me as if it is pronounced "cur" (/**kər**/). The US engine does not produce these pronunciations.

I've looked these up as abbreviations, both with a general google search and in the OED online, since the TTS engine frequently defaults to words as abbreviations (for example, the common name Ed always becomes editor, and the word "no" at the end of a sentence would be read as "number").

If this were the case, I would think "honourable" would be the obvious default British pronunciation of "hon", or possibly "honorary".

For M', something relating to *machines* or *mass* seems possible, but they don't seem like the *first* association (the OED has six other definitions for M preceding the mathematical symbol for mass, and does not include machine at all). These also don't explain where the second syllable comes from.

So, my questions:

> 1. Is there an English rule, or a British usage, that explains the
>      **pronunciation of *m'* as /ˈmæʃ-nə/** and/or
> 2. Is there an English rule, or a British usage, that explains the
>      **pronunciation of *hon* as /kər/**?

I'm willing to accept that this might just be a bug in the engine (which would be out-of-scope for ELL), but most mispronunciations are clearly the product of over-regularization rather than pure error.

---

Clarification of why I believe this question is on-topic here:

I thought I was clear about this, but I'm NOT interested in the mechanics of how TTS engines work, nor am I assuming that the engine's pronunciations are "correct" for any variety of English. Rather, I am interested in what over-regularizations produced by machines relying on the rules given it by English speakers can tell us about English. (Similarly, linguists have looked at the over-regularizations produced by children learning to speak a language to identify underlying structures of the language.) I am also interested in the differences between American- and British-English usage, as occasionally (incidentally) revealed by listening to a TTS engine predicated on British English input.

Clarification 2: One more piece of information that may help understand why these examples, in particular, are of interest to me: Ordinarily, if the TTS doesn't "know" a word (most "common" words were apparently entered wholesale, rather than relying on "rules"), it will either sound it out using fairly basic rules—which in the case of "hon" I would expect to produce something like hot-ending-with-an-n or con-starting-with-an-h or similar—or else it simply spells out the word, in cases where it doesn't follow normal patterns of English spelling (common with loan words and uncommon names). In these *two* cases (out of thousands of unique words I've listened to), neither of these strategies was employed and I have been unable to identify a logical reason. For comparison, "'ave" as in "'ave a good day, guv'nor" is pronounced "avenue" by one TTS engine, and "ah-vay" as in "Ave Maria" in another; both of these examples are clearly comprehensible based on English usage, even if a native speaker would not make that mistake.

Comment: ***Don't*** assume text-to-speech facilities "know" how to pronounce words. To a considerable extent, they don't even know what *words* are, let alone what abbreviated forms like ***Hon*** represent. As I've pointed out before, I had some real hassles when I put together [a routine to enable tts](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,85308.msg767830.html#msg767830) in the Foobar music player. No, *The Who* don't actually ***live*** at Leeds. They made an album when they played a live gig there, but try telling a tts engine how to recognize the difference! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the shortcomings (hardly "bugs") of automated text-to-speech, not use of English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I absolutely *don't* assume that the TTS engine "knows" anything; however, the people who programmed it were relying on what they "know" about how English words are pronounced, and sometimes the errors produced through this process lead to interesting insights into the English language.

Comment: So far as I know, there aren't really any tts engines supporting IPA. Asking how particular sequences of letters in English words are pronounced is *way* too broad / unanswerable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is there ANY English dialect you know of in which "hon" would be pronounced like the English word "cur"? I don't. But I do know a case where "col" is pronounced like the English word "kernel". I am wondering whether something like that has happened here. Would the case be different if I said that I had heard an immigrant to Britain, who generally speaks with a (to my American ear) authentic British accent, had used a word unfamiliar to me, and I was wondering whether it was a Britishism or an error on the non-native speaker's part? What if the case was a British four-year-old?

Comment: M for Monsieur??

Comment: @StevenLittman Yes, I considered that, but if that's what she's going for, it's the most execrable French accent I've ever heard for this fairly familiar word. The (spurious) 'n' clearly follows the 'sh' sound, and the first vowel is the *a* in cat or hat. I would link to a recording if I could, but I don't have the technical know-how to capture and post audio.

Comment: Try putting it in American accent mode and see what that voice comes up with.

Comment: @StevenLittman That is a brilliantly obvious suggestion. In American English, it pronounces both sounds as I would expect (something like muh and hun). However, in running the test I've noticed that "m'self" is, in fact, pronounced correctly by the UK engine; it is only "m'lady" and "m'lord" (of the three samples that I tried) that produce the strange word (it says lord and lady properly, so you get "mash-nuh-lady" and "mash-nuh-lord"). I've edited the question to include those facts.

Comment: Also, I have not reproduced the "hon" issue; it may have been corrected since I last encountered it. I will try to find one of the original sources where I heard it, to see if it is also context-dependent.

Comment: @nedibes: You seem to be asking us to second-guess exactly what assumptions a programmer might have (deliberately or as an unanticipated side-effect) introduced into his software. It really doesn't have much to do with language as such. It's unrealistic to attempt to "reverse-engineer" the actual rules of pronunciation by studying things tts engines get wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I am asking whether the spoken "mashna-lady" etc. would be understood by (at least some) British English speakers or, absent that, if there was an obvious, basic rule for parsing written English that I had missed. Possibly the answer to both is "no", but I don't see how I could know that *before* asking the question. I don't see this as different from questions asking about other aberrant written or spoken words or phrases that might be a typo or a mis-speaking, but might also be something the questioner hasn't run across before.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I was suggesting that I don't know much about British English usage, and I might have missed something that would be known to a native BrE speaker. Not necessarily obvious, but something a BrE speaker with an enthusiasm for the language could figure out.

Comment: You mention BrE a lot. In practice, the vast majority of phonemes peculiar to BrE can be directly mapped onto phonemes peculiar to, say, AmE. Which means that *in principle* a tts engine could switch accents simply by remapping to a different "output phoneme set". In that context, I think looking for some BrE pronunciation quirk to explain the howlers you've discovered seems to me like a bit of a wild goose chase.

Comment: For the first issue, I've seen M' used in surnames, (e.g. M'Intosh, as a variant of McIntosh).

Answer (score 3):

1. No, generally "m'" is vocalised as a quick 'muh' sound.
2. 'hon' is never pronounced /kər/. In the case of 'honey', /hʌn/ would be correct, in case of 'honourable' (hon. as an abbreviation), then /ˈɒn/ (somewhere between 'ahn', 'on') would be about right.

Comment: I wonder if the M' is interpreted as 'master'.

Comment: Or the French "Monsieur"?